# Atualizar os dados de uma página HTML com JSP

Tags: html5, jsp

Estou fazendo um sistema simples em JSP, onde o programa deve simplesmente buscar um float num Banco de Dados e em seguida somar a uma variável. Tudo está funcionando, porém não consigo fazer com que essa informação seja mostrada pelo HTML, segue meu código:

```
<form name="orc" method="post" action="#">
    <select name="tratamentos">
            <%float preco = 0;
            Integer x = 0;
            DAOTratamento dao = new DAOTratamento();
            ArrayList<Tratamento> listaTratamento = new ArrayList<Tratamento>();
            listaTratamento = dao.searchAll();
            for(Tratamento t : listaTratamento){%>
            <option value=<%out.println("tratamento"+x); x++%> ><%out.println(t.getNome());%></option>
            <% } %>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Adicionar"/>
            </form>
             <% 
                       String s = request.getParameter("tratamentos");
                       if (s !=null)
                       {
                           Tratamento tratamento = new Tratamento();
                           tratamento = dao.searchByName(s);
                           preco+= tratamento.getPreco();
                       }
              %>
              <h1>Preço: R$<%out.println(preco);%></h1>
```

Comment: O que está acontecendo? O que deveria acontecer?

Comment: Não está acontecendo nada e deveria atualizar o valor mostrado no <h1>Preço: R$<%out.println(preco);%></h1>